# How to show an ImageView in a style?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles

Before, when my app first started up, there was a white screen. So I created a style with a black background in styles.xml and referenced it in my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".InitialScreen"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

styles.xml:

```
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#000</item>
</style>
```

The black screen shows successfully, How can I show an ImageView in this style?

Answer (score 0):

In your mipmap/drawables folder of your project add an image of your choice. Inside your style remove the background and add a windowBackground... inside reference your drawable or mipmap that you have added.

E.G:

I want my background to be a certain image, it's name will be `background.png`. I will go to the directory of my project and add this image to the drawables or mipmaps folder, depending on which you're using. In your style have this:

```
android:windowBackground="@drawable/background"
```

Or `@mipmap/background` depending on which you are using.

**Why I have used windowBackground and not background**

I have just recently done the same thing and realized that I had made a mistake when using background instead of windowBackground because if you have a layout/view which has no background specified it will use the same background. This will cause the background to repeat.

**Hope I helped,**

**-Daniel**